# Laravel blade replaces + with - in string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Hello I have very strange problem with Laravel Blade.

I have object `$studio` which holds attribute `clean_name`, when I do:

```
{{dd($studio)}}
```

I get for `clean_name` this: `Studio+Name`, but when I actually echo that to `anchor` tag like this:

```
<a href="/studio/{{$studio->clean_name}}">Studio</a>
```

or like this:

```
<a href="/studio/{!!$studio->clean_name!!}">Studio</a>
```

I get that my link is:
`/studio/Studio-Name`

So it actually replaces + with -, any solution for that?

Comment: can you show me $studio array data?

Comment: please add your dd($studio->clean_name)

Comment: you can follow @User's Instruction.
convert you $studio to json then access it

Comment: @User way worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have tried like this it's working fine for me

json object like this:

> {"id":22,"first_name":"Studio+Name","last_name":"Studio","user_name":"Studio","email":"Studio@gmail.com","created_at":"2015-09-11
>   10:11:29","updated_at":"2015-09-11 10:11:29"}

In blade file i have wrote like this

```
{{$show}}
<a href="/localhost:8090/{{$show->first_name}}">Studio</a>
```

In Url it displayed like this

> localhost:8090/Studio+Name